# d3js dynamic csv switch from dropdown list

Tags: java, javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm new to d3js, and I'm successfully using example here: https://gist.github.com/d3noob/4414436

That's quite nice, because it works remotely, the CSV being stored on server side.
Now, I'd like to go further, and add the ability to select the source CSV from a list and the redraw the chart.

I'm stuck in writing php and  java, and java echo'ed by php, so I think that I'm totally on the wrong way.

Would you have an example that illustrates how to perform the chart update reading a new CSV selected from a dropdown list containing the server side's CSV pathes?

Kind regards,

Sylvain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't need help making the drop-down list. The simplest method would be to simply feed in the drop-down list selection into a `var`, and use that `var` when you do your `d3.csv()` call. For example:

```
//storing the drop-down selection in the ddSelection var
var ddSelection = document.getElementById("secondOption").value,

//feeding that to create the csv filename you want
var csvFile = "/some server path/" + ddSelection + ".csv";

d3.csv(csvFile, function(error, dataset) {
    //a bunch of cool visualizing stuff
})
```

Then you'll just need to remember to include `.exit()` when you're joining your data, so that the graph updates with the new dataset - Mike Bostock's [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) is the standard reference for that.

Comment: Wonderful.
Now I'm able to choose which CSV to display graphically.

Many thanks.

I'm closing the thread.